# Least sum of distances

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization, problem-solving

- **Problem:**

Let $A, B, C, D$ be points in a $3$-dimensional space.

Find the point $X$ that minimizes the sum of the distances $AX+ BX + CX + DX$.

---

- **Context:**

During a course, I was assigned a problem about minimizing the sums of the squares of the distances of one point from other points in a plane.

Now, I am curious about what methods I can use to tackle and make some progresses with this more general question.

Comment: This is a very complicated problem. (Minimizing the sum of the **squares** of the distances is easy.) For some information, [please see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much for your reply. I know that it is a complex matter, but I was wondering if there could be an accessible way to have some results in the case I described.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the beautiful book *[The Mathematical Mechanic. Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8861.html)* [[1](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8861.html)], professor Mark Levi offered the following mechanical proof of the fact that $ \angle{AXB} = \angle{CXD} $ and that the two angles are bisected by the same line (*N.B.*: the same result holds for any different pairing of these points).

Let us take four identical constant tension springs (*i.e.*, whose tension is independent of their elongation) of tension $ T = 1 $ and connect them as shown in the picture ([[1](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8861.html)], p. 62).

[image: Figure 1]

It is clear that the potential energy of each spring is equal to its length, and that the potential energy of the system is equal to the combined length of the springs. It follows that the minimal-length configuration has minimal potential energy. Consequently, it corresponds to an equilibrium, and thus to the vanishing of the sum of the forces $ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c} $, and $ \mathbf{d} $ acting upon the point $ X $:

\begin{equation} \tag{1} 
 \mathbf {a} + \mathbf{b}= - (\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{d}).
\end{equation}

The springs have identical constant tension: $|\mathbf{a}|= |\mathbf{b}| = |\mathbf{c}| = |\mathbf{d}|=1$. Hence, the vector $ \mathbf {a} + \mathbf{b} $ lies on the bisector
   of $ \angle{AXB} $ and the vector $ \mathbf{c} + \mathbf{d} $ lies on
   the bisector of $ \angle{CXD} $. From (1), it follows that these
   bisectors lie on the same line.

Furthermore, the fact that $|\mathbf{a}|= |\mathbf{b}| = |\mathbf{c}| = |\mathbf{d}|=1$ implies that $\mathbf {|a + b|} = 2\cos(\angle{AXB})$ and $\mathbf{|c + d|} = 2\cos(\angle{CXD})$. From (1), we have $ \angle{AXB} = \angle
   {CXD} $.

---

**Reference:**

[1](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8861.html) Levi, M., 2009: *[The Mathematical Mechanic. Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8861.html)*. Princeton University Press, pp. 61-63, 161-162.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I love these kinds of intuitive methods to deal with difficult problems.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

- **Two-dimensional space**

Let $A=(x_1,y_1),B=(x_2,y_2),C=(x_3,y_3),D = (x_4,y_4),X = (x,y)$.

Then, $$AX+ BX + CX + DX=\big((x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2\big)^{\frac12}+\big((x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2\big)^{\frac12}+\big((x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2\big)^{\frac12}+\big((x-x_4)^2+(y-y_4)^2\big)^{\frac12}$$

This is an extreme-value problem of a function of several variables. You can compute the stationary point of this function; then compare the value...