# Least sum of power of distances

Tags: calculus, analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

> Let $n$ points in a $3$-dimensional space. Find the point $X$ that
>   minimizes the sum of distances $\|A_1X\|^q+ \|A_2X\|^q + ...
>  +\|A_nX\|^q $ (where $q \in \mathbb{Q^+}$).

Are there any general *intuitive* methods to tackle this problem?

Comment: What is $A_1, A_2,\ldots$ ? And what do you mean by $\| A_nX\|$ ?

Comment: @Integral they are the n points in space and that is the distance of a point from the point X

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947887/least-sum-of-distances/947982#947982) is a related question.

Comment: If $q = 0$ then the choice of $X$ is irrelevant. If $q < 0$ then we can only choose $X=\infty$. I think we should restrict to $q \in \mathbb Q^+$.

Comment: @kennytm Edited.

Comment: When $q=2$, this is the centroid $\frac1n(A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n)$. When $q=1$ it is the [geometric median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median). When $q\to\infty$ it is the center of the [smallest enclosing circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem). For other $q$ there is no closed form solution in general, so I don't think an "intuitive" method is possible.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. If you elaborate some more, that comment can become a nice answer.